# How to keep readme from being web accessible

Tags: git, .htaccess, web

I have a plain text readme file that is in the root directory of my website which is version controlled with Git. I like to have the readme there because GitHub will display it when viewing that repo.

However, when I go to `mysite.com/readme.md`, I get the readme file back. I do not want this file to be accessible to the public.

What is the best way to effectively disallow the public from accessing this readme file without moving the file away from the root of the project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many different ways depending on how github accesses this, you'd add some stuff to the htaccess file in your document root (or where your readme file is).

Using mod_authz:

```
<Files "readme.md">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

This will return a 403 forbidden for *all requests* to `/readme.md`. If you want to whitelist a specific IP, You can add this right above the `Deny from all` line:

```
Allow from 12.34.56.78
```

which will whitelist requests sent from the 12.34.56.78 IP.

Using mod_rewrite (which gives you a couple of options)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^readme\.md$ - [L,F]
```

This does the same thing. To whitelist an IP, add this before the `RewriteRule` line:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.56\.78$
```

You can also return a 404 instead of a 403 Forbidden by replacing the `F` in the rewrite flags to `R=404`. If you need to whitelist a referer, you can add a condition (right above the rewriterule line) like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://github\.com/ [NC]
```

which will allow people to access the readme.md file if the link was embedded on a page from `github.com`.

Comment: How do you do this using express?